# Order menu nodes by parent, previous and next id

Tags: c#

I have a small menu which I would like to order by the DB table id like the following:

```
  public class Obj
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int? ParentNodeId { get; set; }
        public int? PreviousNodeId { get; set; }
        public int? NextNodeId { get; set; }
    }

 private IEnumerable<MenuNodeDTO> GetSortedMenuNodes(int menuId)
    {
        var nodes = LoadMenuNodes(menuId);
        foreach (MenuNode menuNode in nodes
            .Where(s => s.MenuItemId == null && s.ParentNodeId == null)
            .OrderBy(x => x?.PreviousNodeId)
            .Where(x => x.PreviousNodeId != x.Id))
        {
            MenuNodeDTO tmpMenuNode = new MenuNodeDTO();
            tmpMenuNode.MenuNodeDtoId = menuNode.Id;
            tmpMenuNode.MenuItemCode = menuNode.MenuItem?.Code;
            tmpMenuNode.ChildMenuNodes = GetChildNodes(menuNode).ToList();
            tmpMenuNode.MenuSettings = GetMenuSettings(menuNode).ToList();
            yield return tmpMenuNode;
        }
}
```

**Example:**

```
Id = 1 MainMenuPoint1 ParentNodeId = null, PreviousNodeId = null, NextNodeId = 4
Id = 2 -> 1 ChildNodeFromPoint1 ParentNodeId = 1, PreviousNodeId = null, NextNodeId = null
Id = 3  --> ChildNodeFromFirstChildNode1 ParentNodeId = 2, PreviousNodeId = null, NextNodeId = null
Id = 4 MainMenuPoint2 ParentNodeId = null, PreviousNodeId = 1, NextNodeId = null
```

The problem with my for each is that when the id changed the ordering not works.
Has someone a idea how to order by parentid, previousid and next id which check every time all ids for the relationship?

Comment: As for me, I would suggest another DB structure: `ParentNodeId` and `Order`. You would able to use DFS to order your nodes, and `Order` for ordering leaves. Order should not be guaranteed to be distinct as well, all children items of node 1 can have order = 0 - it means that they should be sorted by name \ ID \ whatever else, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev the problem then is what would you do when you will change the menu structure, move a node or delete a node ?

Comment: Talking about order, removing or moving a node changes nothing - it works great. Talking about parent relationship, you simply cannot delete a node if it has child nodes. That's the question of data integrity. You need to clear its child nodes list before removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private IEnumerable<MenuNodeDTO> GetSortedNodes(Menu menu, MenuNode node)
        {
            List<MenuNodeDTO> items = new List<MenuNodeDTO>();

            var nodes = node != null ? node.ChildMenuNodes : menu.MenuNodes;
            var nextNode = node == null
                ? nodes.Where(c => c.PreviousNodeId == null && c.ParentNodeId == null).FirstOrDefault()
                : nodes.Where(c => c.ParentNodeId == node.Id && c.PreviousNodeId == null).FirstOrDefault();

            while (nextNode != null)
            {
                MenuNodeDTO tmpMenuNode = new MenuNodeDTO();
                tmpMenuNode.MenuNodeDtoId = nextNode.Id;
                tmpMenuNode.MenuItemCode = nextNode?.MenuItem?.Code;
                tmpMenuNode.ChildMenuNodes = this.GetSortedNodes(menu, nextNode).ToList();
                tmpMenuNode.MenuSettings = GetMenuSettings(nextNode).ToList();
                items.Add(tmpMenuNode);
                if (!nextNode.NextNodeId.HasValue) break;
                nextNode = nextNode.NextNode;
            }
            return items;
        }
```